# Multiplication of real and complex radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals

If I have, for example, the product

$\sqrt{7+\sqrt{22}}\sqrt[3]{38+i\sqrt{6}} $

Can I perform the multiplication or this cannot be done and only remains to leave the product in this form?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous, because there is no such thing as a radical for complex numbers. It's not well defined, because you can't choose a specific complex number for your function (on $\mathbb R$ we choose the positive one).

So if you define $\sqrt.$ properly, may be you could perform your product, but it seems a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another answer, the radical isn't an easy thing to understand for complex numbers. However, we can simplify it by taking the "principle branch".

For a complex number, we get that $a+bi=z=|z|e^{i(\theta+2k\pi)}$ for any integer $k$ (see below), where $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the distance from the origin in the complex plane and $\theta=\arctan(b/a)$ is the angle with the positive real axis. Here we will let $k=0$ only for simplicity. Hence $z^{1/n}=|z|^{1/n}e^{i\theta/n}.$

Now we will use Euler's identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta.$ (This is a well know fact from higher mathematics.)

$$z^{1/n}=|z|^{1/n}\left(\cos(\theta/n)+i\sin(\theta/n)\right).$$

So now, you just have to turn your complex numbers into their respective polar forms, take the "principle roots" and then multiply/distribute as per usual algebraic operations.

You example has $z=38+i\sqrt{6}.$ This gives $|z|=\sqrt{38^2+6}=\sqrt{1450}=5\sqrt{2\cdot29}$ and $\theta=\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38).$

Thus $$z^{1/3}=5^{1/3}58^{1/6}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)}{3}\right)\right).$$

Now just multiply this by $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{22}}$ to get

$$\left(7+\sqrt{22}\right)^{1/2}\cdot 5^{1/3}\cdot 58^{1/6}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)}{3}\right)\right).$$

This can now be evaluated in a calculator in order to get a decimal approximation: $11.5003+0.2468i.$

Of course, the general solution is

$$\left(7+\sqrt{22}\right)^{1/2}\cdot 5^{1/3}\cdot 58^{1/6}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)+2k\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{6}/38)+2k\pi}{3}\right)\right)$$

for $k=0,1,2.$ Since we took a cube root, we have to find three distinct roots.

**Why the $2k\pi$?**

When you think of a complex number as a point in the complex plane, you should realize it can be characterized by its distance from the origin and the angle it makes with the positive real axis. So if we rotate around the origin by $360^\circ$, then we end up back at the same point. This is where the $2k\pi=360^\circ \cdot k$ comes from.

Answer (score -2):

$\sqrt{7+\sqrt{22}}\sqrt[3]{38+\sqrt6i}=
\sqrt[6]{(7+\sqrt{22})^3}\sqrt[6]{(38+\sqrt6i)^2}=
\sqrt[6]{(7+\sqrt{22})^3(38+\sqrt6i)^2}=
\sqrt[6]{1157590+243022\sqrt{22}+(61180\sqrt6+25688\sqrt{33})i}$

EDIT:
Other possible valid results are the above result multiplied by $\left(\cos{\frac{k\pi}3}+i\sin{\frac{k\pi}3}\right)\text{, where}\;k=\{1\dots 5\}$

Comment: If you think this answer is correct at all, then I have a lovely proof that $-1 = 1$ for you...

Comment: @Najib Idrissi \ I am certain that you do not intend to be snotty. What DO you intend?

Comment: Your answer is utter nonsense. This is what I intended my comment to mean.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi \ Well, then, you must have a conception of what the correct answer is. Teach me, master.

Comment: There is no correct answer, because the question itself is malformed... $\sqrt[3]{38+i\sqrt{6}}$ is not an expression that makes sense as a number. At best it's a multivalued function. By the way, consider this if you still believe your answer makes sense: $-1 = i^2 = \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$... What gives? Or this: $-1 = \sqrt[3]{(-1)^3} = \sqrt[6]{(-1)^6} = \sqrt[6]{1} = 1$...!

Comment: I tried to be somewhat humorous with my first comment, maybe it didn't show, but if you're going to react like that I don't see the point.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi \ I was, and am, sincere in my refusal to believe that you intended to be snotty, because I have, over and over, seen that you are among the most helpful at MSE. So, the crux is that you want the other five possible answers, as well; is that it?